# Creating Android 2.3 apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm obsessed with old phones, and remember using my android 2.1.1 phone in the past and my android 2.3 tablet right now. I hate waste and believe that I can make these machines better with creating apps that's appropriate for today's needs. But how? Android Studio isn't easy to use espicially with API 9. I wish that I get some engines or ways to make apps for android 2.3.

Comment: Back before Android Studio existed, Eclipse was the IDE that was commonly used for Android development, together with some plugins for integrating with the Android SDK. If/where you can find those tools and information on how to use them, I don't know.

Comment: You can try Eclipse for Android Developers. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/neon/m6/eclipse-android-developers

Comment: I don't see how it's a question? You realize that writing for outdated hardware with dropped support is a huge pain since you have to use matching outdated tools and will be forced to sift through ancient answers if anything goes wrong since you won't get any up to date help.

Comment: Might also find it useful to try using Android Studio 2.3.3, can find it in the archive: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive. I'm fairly sure that's the version I successfully used to build my API 10 apps, atleast 4-5 years ago. Be prepared to change support libs, gradle versions, max sdk etc. for your project. Just trying to get it working again myself, not much luck yet though (mainly emulator issues, builds fine).